# Ruby library to make multiple HTTP requests simultaneously

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm looking for an alternate Ruby HTTP library that makes multiple HTTP calls simultaneously and performs better than the core Net::HTTP library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for Typhoeus.

> Typhoeus runs HTTP requests in parallel while cleanly encapsulating handling logic

https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a networking library handle parallelism? That is exactly what threads are for.

```
require "open-uri"

fetcher = lambda do |uri|
  puts "Started fetching #{uri}"
  puts open(uri).read
  puts "Stopped fetching #{uri}"
end

thread1 = Thread.new("http://localhost:9292", &fetcher)
thread2 = Thread.new("http://localhost:9293", &fetcher)

thread1.join
thread2.join
```

Also, I don't understand what do you mean by "performs better". Core libraries are usually good enough to be in the core. Do you have any problems with Net::HTTP?

Comment: Typhoeus exists and handles this problem fantastically, I don't see any reason you would reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Parallel gem, it should work with any Ruby HTTP library.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it performs better then Typhoeus, BUT you could use Eventmacheine + em-http-request. There is an example for sending multiple requests.

```ruby
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'

EventMachine.run {
  multi = EventMachine::MultiRequest.new

  reqs = [
    'http://google.com/',
    'http://google.ca:81/'
  ]

  reqs.each_with_index do |url, idx|
    http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url, :connect_timeout => 1)
    req = http.get
    multi.add idx, req
  end

  multi.callback  do
    p multi.responses[:callback].size
    p multi.responses[:errback].size
    EventMachine.stop
  end
}
```

https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request